# Images placed in blocks do not show up on certain pages

Tags: blocks, media

I hope this is not a silly question. I have created some links to social media using images inside custom blocks. The images show up on every single page on my local testing server, but after uploading to my production server, I notice that on pages where I use URL aliases that are not directly attached to the site url, the images don't show up. For example if I the page address is www.thebeat99.com/sandbox/competitions, the images show up just fine. If the page address is www.thebeat99.com/sandbox/profile/dami, the images don't show up. I have tried adding a base url in the settings.php file but it does not work either.

This is an example of the html I use to embed the images:

```
<div class="beaticon" id="fbicon">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/thebeat999fm">
    <img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="sites/default/files/buttons/fbicon.png" width="15" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: add few more information or code piece you used in the block to explain further

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "/sandbox/" before sites like below
(src="/sandbox/sites/default/files/buttons/fbicon.png")

```
<div class="beaticon" id="fbicon">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/thebeat999fm">
        <img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="/sandbox/sites/default/files/buttons/fbicon.png" width="15" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Or add "/" before sites as src="/sites/default/files/buttons/fbicon.png" and set your base url to http://www.thebeat99.com/sandbox

Comment: This worked for me. I'm wondering why though. So if I move it to a different server, I will have to rename all my links again. Is there a way that this works without changing every time I move the site. Thank you

Comment: Never build urls explicitly: create them in code using the l() or url() functions. That's what they are for, to ensure portability.

Comment: Your Drupal installation is inside the /sandbox directory. so better if you can use the base url as "http://www.thebeat99.com/sandbox" instead of the 1st option I mentioned. If you do it in that way follow the same folder structure in your local dev environment too.